# How to display the right coverage for unit-tests in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, coverage.py

I am having trouble displaying the correct coverage info for unittest.  I created a simple python file as such: simple.py that contains the following contents:

```
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y
```

and a unittest as such called test_simple.py that i stored under the tests folder:

```
import unittest

import simple as si


class TestSimple(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_multiply(self):
        self.assertEqual(si.multiply(3, 4), 12)
```

Now, im. using pytest and coverage.py to run my coverage report.  I ran the following statements:

```
pytest test_simple.py --cov=simple
```

and see the following:

```
coverage report -m

Name        Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
simple.py       8      3    62%   5, 8, 11
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL           8      3    62%
```

Why would this show 62%?  shouldn't it 25%?  it seems its adding 100% from my test file and 25% from the file i want to see how much percent is covered, and taking the average of the two...which gives me 62.5%.  is there anyway i can show the correct info which is 25%?  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the HTML output (`pytest --cov=simple --cov-report=html`, then open `htmlcov/index.html`), and you may find the answer more obvious:

[image]

The metrics are reporting coverage based on the *number of statements* in your code. Not "number of functions". There are 8 statements in your code:

- 4 `def` statements
- 4 `return` statements

Your tests execute all four `def` statements, because that's what happens when you `import` a file, and then one `return` statement (for the `multiply` function).

```
>>> 5/8
0.625
```

Comment: Hey even when I do from simple import multiply, it’s showing 4 def statements as being covered and 3 return statements as not being covered.  Is there anyway I can show just the functions not being covered?

Comment: No. Importing a file executes all the top-level statements (function and class definitions and any other "bare code").

Comment: when I do 
from simple import multiply, you are telling me it’s importing the whole file even though I’m importing only one function?

Comment: That's correct. Python doesn't know what functions are declared in that file until *after* it has executed all the top-level statements.